# Polymorphic has-many-through relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to set up a polymorphic has-many-through relationship with ActiveRecord. Here's the end goal:

- **Users** can belong to many organizations and many teams
- **Organizations** have many users and many teams
- **Teams** have many users and belong to an organization

I am trying to use has-many-through instead of has-and-belongs-to-many, since I need to associate some information along with the relationships (like user role in the organization or team), so I made a join table **Membership**.

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I would design the schema like this:
[image]

- `Organization` has many `Team`
- `Team` has many `TeamMember`
- `User` has many `TeamMember`
- `TeamMember` belongs to `User` and `Team`

The models will be:

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :team_members, through: :teams
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization # fk: organization_id
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :teams, through: :team_members
  has_many :organizations, though: :teams
end
```

**team_member.rb**

```
class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team      # fk: team_id
  belongs_to :user      # fk: user_id
  attr_accessible :role # role in team
end
```

So, compare with your requirements:

> Users can belong to many organizations and many teams

=> Okay

> Organizations have many users and many teams

=> Okay

> Teams have many users and belong to an organization

=> Okay

Btw, we don't use any polymorphic here, and `TeamMember` stands for `Membership` in your early idea!

Answer (score 1):

For polymorphic association,

```
class User
  has_many :memberships
end

class Team
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :memberships, :as => :membershipable #you decide the name
end

class Organization
  has_many :memberships, :as => :membershipable
  has_many :teams
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :membershipable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Note that `User` is indirectly associated to `Team` and `Organization`, and that every call has to go through `Membership`.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I use a `Relationship` class (in a gem I've named `ActsAsRelatingTo`) as the join model. It looks something like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: acts_as_relating_to_relationships
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  owner_id            :integer
#  owner_type          :string
#  in_relation_to_id   :integer
#  in_relation_to_type :string
#  created_at          :datetime         not null
#  updated_at          :datetime         not null
#

module ActsAsRelatingTo
  class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

      validates :owner_id,                  presence: true
      validates :owner_type,                presence: true
      validates :in_relation_to_id,         presence: true
      validates :in_relation_to_type,       presence: true

      belongs_to  :owner,                   polymorphic: true
      belongs_to  :in_relation_to,          polymorphic: true

  end
end
```

So, in your `User` model, you would say something like:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :owned_relationships,
      as: :owner,
      class_name: "ActsAsRelatingTo::Relationship",
      dependent: :destroy

    has_many :organizations_i_relate_to, 
      through: :owned_relationships, 
      source: :in_relation_to, 
      source_type: "Organization"

    ...

  end
```

I believe you may be able to leave the `source_type` argument off since the joined class (`Organization`) can be inferred from `:organizations`. Often, I'm joining models where the class name cannot be inferred from the relationship name, in which case I include the `source_type` argument.

With this, you can say `user.organizations_i_relate_to`. You can do the same set up for a relationship between any set of classes.

You could also say in your `Organization` class:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :referencing_relationships,
      as: :in_relation_to,
      class_name: "ActsAsRelatingTo::Relationship",
      dependent: :destroy

    has_many :users_that_relate_to_me, 
      through: :referencing_relationships, 
      source: :owner, 
      source_type: "User"
```

So that you could say `organization.users_that_relate_to_me`.

I got tired of having to do all the set up, so in my gem I created an `acts_as_relating_to` method so I can do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_relating_to :organizations, :teams
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_relating_to :users, :organizations
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_relating_to :organizations, :users
  ...
end
```

and all the polymorphic associations and methods get set up for me "automatically".

Sorry for the long answer. Hope you find something useful in it.